# Not able to use realtime local emulator database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, local, firebase-tools

I followed some tutorials to use local emulators on my laptop.
the installation went well and I could start the emulator.

I see the realtime Database in green and can see the empty DB.

But from there, I am not able to do anything at all:

> Import a DB: I get the following error: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

> Adding some fields/Values in the Database from the GUI:
> - I don't have any "+" sign to add values.
> - I cannot save the values I put.
> - I can see "Edit" or "Delete" button, but they have no effect...

There is something going wrong somewhere and that may be due to some config, but I don't know what that should be.
I don't find documentation relatively and did not find any "Google" article relatively.

Any support would be very welcome as I am currently blocked with my project.

Thank you.

LOGS:
**database-debug.log**

```
*Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.9.0.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
17:34:03.761 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
17:34:03.894 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at 127.0.0.1:9000*
```

**firebase-debug.log**

```
*_[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.410Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.412Z] Command: /usr/local/bin/firebase /root/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase emulators:start
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.412Z] CLI Version: 11.12.0
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.412Z] Platform: linux
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.412Z] Node Version: v16.16.0
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.412Z] Time: Fri Sep 30 2022 17:34:02 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.413Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug]
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.471Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.472Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (ebonnefoy@rbbn.com)
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.481Z] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.513Z] openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.514Z] OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1, mixed mode, sharing)
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.523Z] Parsed Java major version: 11
[info] i emulators: Starting emulators: auth, database {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: auth, database"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.536Z] [hub] writing locator at /tmp/hub-testemul01.json
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.543Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/testemul01 [none]
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.747Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/testemul01 200
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.748Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/testemul01 {"projectId":"testemul01","projectNumber":"820099885379","displayName":"testemul1","name":"projects/testemul01","resources":{"hostingSite":"testemul01"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_e1300143-b10e-4def-88a1-a6736b7b5a04"}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.749Z] database rules config: []
[warn] ⚠ database: Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file. The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file. The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration."}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.758Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.758Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.758Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: rules {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: rules"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.758Z] Starting Database Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.9.0.jar","--host","127.0.0.1","--port",9000],"optionalArgs":["port","host","functions_emulator_port","functions_emulator_host"],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Starting Database Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.9.0.jar","--host","127.0.0.1","--port",9000],"optionalArgs":["port","host","functions_emulator_port","functions_emulator_host"],"joinArgs":false}"}}
[info] i database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Database Emulator logging to \u001b[1mdatabase-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:02.771Z] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g\n"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:03.258Z] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.9.0.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred\nWARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.9.0.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys\nWARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil\nWARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations\nWARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release\n"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:03.763Z] 17:34:03.761 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"17:34:03.761 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started\n"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:03.895Z] 17:34:03.894 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at 127.0.0.1:9000
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"database"},"message":"17:34:03.894 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at 127.0.0.1:9000\n"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:09.740Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:09.740Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: port {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: port"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:09.741Z] Starting Emulator UI with command {"binary":"node","args":["/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.9.0/server/server.js"],"optionalArgs":[],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Starting Emulator UI with command {"binary":"node","args":["/root/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.9.0/server/server.js"],"optionalArgs":[],"joinArgs":false}"}}
[info] i ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Emulator UI logging to \u001b[1mui-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
[debug] [2022-10-01T00:34:09.903Z] Web / API server started at 127.0.0.1:4000
{"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Web / API server started at 127.0.0.1:4000\n"}}
[info]
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔ All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator │ Host:Port │ View in Emulator UI │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth │
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ Database │ 127.0.0.1:9000 │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/database │
└────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
Other reserved ports: 4500*
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a JSON object as the first item in the database? Does that allow you to add further (sub-)objects in the database?

Comment: Hello Chris, 
No, I'm not able to add anything in the DB.

I've got the following (testemul01 is the name of my DB).
http://127.0.0.1:9000/?ns=testemul01:  - "Edit Value"/"Delete Value" => None of this options result in any modification.

I tried to import a DB, but it results with an error.

I am able to create a user in the Auth DB, but that has no effect on the Realtime DB.

I don't have any "+" button to add sub-objects, unfortunately.
I may be missing some option/config somewhere, but I'm not able to identify which one.

We can screen share to make trouble-shooting easier.